# App Crashed while getting Received Memory Warning while using PDF

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

I am using vrf Reader 2.5.6 to support from iOS 4.3 for viewing pdf and with zoom options, If i continuously browse the pdf views after some time it is displaying recived memory warning message in console.

I have checked the leak using Profile, it shows only on leak But it showing initial launch of app not while using pdf.

[image]

I am struck at this point. Please check my attached screenshot and give me idea to over come this issue.

Comment: Handle `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. and release some of objects which can be recreated later

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project into ARC.

OR you should  release all the objects , variables, arrays etc..you created after used.

I hope it will help you.